# Apache uses it's own 404 handler instead of index.php for .txt files

Tags: php, apache

I want to serve all requests for non-existing files via .php

`.htaccess` configuration:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

This does seem to mostly work but some specific file extensions (.txt,.jpg, some more?) get handled by apache instead of getting passed through php.
http://localhost:8000/home -> shows homepage
http://localhost:8000/file.zip (does not exist) -> shows custom styled 404 page served by PHP

http://localhost:8000/exists.txt (existing file) -> serves existing file
http://localhost:8000/doesnotexist.txt (does not exist) -> shows default apache 404 page (same as when no PHP is installed)

Is there some default apache handler for specific file extensions?
How can I set ALL requests to get passed through index.php?

Using [docker php 7.4 apache as my base image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/php/library/php/7.4-apache/images/sha256-3f04eaed6449ebe2f2969c5f6176f745ae9bcef659f67b6c7fcbe54d8a15a2db?context=explore)

Comment: Does the error still happened if you only have `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` in your .htaccess?

Comment: Q1) Do you have any of those instructions wrapped in a <directory> declaration and the txt files are in a different directory? Q2) Do you do some "handling" in your PHP file? If the PHP file errors it actually redirects you to a "500" page that probably does not exist and this then sends you to a page that looks like the default 404. You can spot this looking at the redirects and networks calls to see if you are getting a 404 or a 500. Note that a 401 permission error will do the same thing - looks like a 404 but actually isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied your experiment with Docker and the php 7.4-apache image. When opening the url `http://localhost:8000/doesnotexist.txt` I'm transfered to the index.php file as I would expect to be. The bottom three rewrite rules will rewrite everything to index.php.

First off: You have not posted a `docker-compose.yml` or `Dockerfile`, so to be sure: you have to enable the rewriting for Apache by either a command in the dockerfile or a custom Dockerfile like this:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM php:7.4-apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite
```

If you would not have enabled the rewrite, an error 500 should appear, because there are no if-conditions around the rewrite rule.

If you did enable the rewriting, the behaviour is still strange, because even if the line `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` is not there the bottom rewrite should make that the index.php is served anyway. In other words: The bottom three lines in the `.htaccess` would make sure that no 404 is served, because everything is rewritten to the index.php.

When you say 'the default apache 404 page' are you talking about the 'Not found' page?

```
Not Found (H1 tag)
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.52 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 8000
```

Try to remove and rebuild the container, so that no weird caching issue can give problems.

And what about your `index.php`. Is there anything in there that could trigger something strange? Could you post it here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your .htaccess file (without the ErrorDocument part):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?file=$0 [QSA,L]
```

Make sure you output 404 if the code does'nt find the file.

Answer (score 0):

- Is there some default apache handler for specific file extensions?
  No,  there is not such a handler by default.
- How can I set ALL requests to get passed through index.php?

1. `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` is valid.
2. `DirectoryIndex index.php` is valid
3. `RewriteEngine on` is valid
4. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is valid
5. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` is valid
6. `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` is also valid!

Keep in mind that you are not rewriting it to the root /index.php, instead you are rewriting without the slash, and it rewrites to the index.php in the current directory. So if index.php doesn't exist in the current directory, chances it can get into an infinite loop.

Try:

```
ErrorDocument /index.php

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] # use '/index.php' if needed to redirect to root index.php
```

This will redirect that everything exists to index.php, and avoid conflicts with `ErrorDocument`.

But, I think this actually what you mean to do:

```
ErrorDocument /index.php

DirectoryIndex index.php

# remove those rewrite rules
```